# Insert many rows JPA Spring Boot Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

i want to insert many rows to this same table in mysql and have error:

> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

The code is:

```
WpPostmeta wpPostmeta = new WpPostmeta();
wpPostmeta.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
wpPostmeta.setMetaKey("_sku");
wpPostmeta.setMetaValue("");

wpPostmetaService.saveOrUpdate(wpPostmeta);

wpPostmeta.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
wpPostmeta.setMetaKey("_regular_price");
wpPostmeta.setMetaValue(reqularPrice[0]);

wpPostmetaService.saveOrUpdate(wpPostmeta);
```

Service is:

```
public WpPostmeta saveOrUpdate(WpPostmeta wpPostmeta){

    wpPostmetaRepository.save(wpPostmeta);
    wpPostmetaRepository.flush();
    return wpPostmeta;


}
```

And Interface is:

public interface WpPostmetaRepository extends JpaRepository {

```
@Query(value = "Select * from wp_postmeta where post_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true){}
```

How should i insert many rows one by one to this same table?

Comment: Regarding the [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-) you should rather use the `saveAll` operation and not flush each save operation on bulk usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is updating same record. Its just a single row

```
WpPostmeta wpPostmeta = new WpPostmeta();
wpPostmeta.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
wpPostmeta.setMetaKey("_sku");
wpPostmeta.setMetaValue("");

wpPostmetaService.saveOrUpdate(wpPostmeta);

wpPostmeta.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
wpPostmeta.setMetaKey("_regular_price");
wpPostmeta.setMetaValue(reqularPrice[0]);

wpPostmetaService.saveOrUpdate(wpPostmeta);
```

If you want multiple rows it would be like this

```
WpPostmeta wpPostmeta = new WpPostmeta();
wpPostmeta.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
wpPostmeta.setMetaKey("_sku");
wpPostmeta.setMetaValue("");

wpPostmetaService.saveOrUpdate(wpPostmeta);

WpPostmeta wpPostmeta1 = new WpPostmeta();
wpPostmeta1.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
wpPostmeta1.setMetaKey("_regular_price");
wpPostmeta1.setMetaValue(reqularPrice[0]);

wpPostmetaService.saveOrUpdate(wpPostmeta1);
```

Instead you can use saveAll method something like this

```
List<WpPostmeta> lstRecord = new ArrayList<WpPostmeta>();

WpPostmeta wpPostmeta = new WpPostmeta();
wpPostmeta.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
wpPostmeta.setMetaKey("_sku");
wpPostmeta.setMetaValue("");
lstRecord.add(wpPostmeta);


WpPostmeta wpPostmeta1 = new WpPostmeta();
wpPostmeta1.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
wpPostmeta1.setMetaKey("_regular_price");
wpPostmeta1.setMetaValue(reqularPrice[0]);
lstRecord.add(wpPostmeta1);


saveAll(lstRecord);


public Boolean saveAll(List<WpPostmeta> lstData){
    wpPostmetaRepository.saveAll(lstData);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use ArrayList, but i have error: 
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Comment: I think problem is in this line wpPostmeta.setPostId(wpPosts.getId());
 ..  Are you trying to add new data or update a record